# Bounding the smallest discriminant of a quartic polynomial with a fixed splitting field

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a primitive quartic field, and let $\tilde{K}$ be its Galois closure. Consider the set

$$\displaystyle S_K = \{f_4 x^4 + f_3 x^3 + f_2 x^2 + f_1 x + f_0 \in \mathbb{Z}[x,y] : f \text{ splits over } \tilde{K}\}.$$

What is the optimal upper bound, in terms of $\text{Disc}(K)$, of the quantity defined by

$$\displaystyle m_K^2 = \frac{1}{|\Delta_K|} \min_{\substack{f \in S_K \\ \Delta(f) \ne 0}} |\Delta(f)|?$$

A simple upper bound is $O(|\text{Disc}(K)|^{1/2})$. This bound can be obtained by considering the subset of monic polynomials (i.e., $f_4 = 1$) so that the roots of the corresponding polynomial are algebraic integers. Choosing a Minkowski basis for the ring of integers of $K$ then gives the claimed bound.

In particular is it possible to obtain the bound $m_K = O\left(|\Delta_K|^{1/4} \right)$?

Comment: Instead of `$f$ splits over $\overline{K}$, you should write (as in the title) $f$ has splitting field $\overline{K}$, or else $m_K=O(1)$. Also do you mean to relate $m_K$ with $\Delta_K$, or rather with $\Delta_{\overline{K}}$? If it was the first, wouldn't $m_K \ge |\Delta_K|$ from the definition?

Comment: Yes, I should have divided by $\Delta_K$. My apologies